# How to decrease and increase the height of a specific view by onpress on view in flatlist of react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

i have rendered 10 views by using flatlist 1st i want to show the details by incresing the height when a user click on view no 6 and decrease height when user again click on it i have done it but problem is that when i click the view no 6 the height of all the views increases and render the list again from 1st view not from 6th how to increase and decrease the height of a specific view and renders from the same view which is increased

```
const setFunctionality = () => {

        setcount(count + 1)

        if (count % 2 == 0) {
            setinitialHeight(windowWidth > windowHeight ? verticalScale(140) : verticalScale(150))
            setIsViewShown(false)

        }

        else {
            setinitialHeight(windowWidth > windowHeight ? verticalScale(170) : verticalScale(280))
            setIsViewShown(true)
        }

    }

 <View>
            <FlatList
                data={data}
                // keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
                style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff', }}
                contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: '5%' }}
                renderItem={(element) => {
                    
                    return (

                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', flex: 1, width: '100%' }}>


                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setFunctionality()}>
                                <View style={{ paddingLeft: 5, flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1, height: initialHeight, backgroundColor: element.item.Status == 'Open' ? '#B7E6E6' : '#EFA5A5', marginTop: 10, borderRadius: 5, alignContent: 'center', marginHorizontal: 10, }}>



                                    <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff', width: 50, height: 50, borderRadius: 27, alignSelf: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>

                                        <Text style={{ color: element.item.Status == 'Open' ? '#B7E6E6' : '#EFA5A5' }}>{element.item.Status}</Text>
                                    </View>

                                    <View style={{ flex: 1, borderTopRightRadius: 20, borderBottomRightRadius: 20, padding: windowWidth > windowHeight ? moderateScale(10) : moderateScale(15), justifyContent: 'center' }}>


                                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', marginVertical: windowWidth > windowHeight ? verticalScale(5) : verticalScale(5), marginTop: 10 }}>

                                            <Text style={{ color: 'black', fontSize: windowWidth > windowHeight ? moderateScale(14) : moderateScale(12), fontFamily: 'DMSans-Bold' }}>Customer ID: {element.item.CusId}</Text>
                                            <Text style={{ color: 'black', fontSize: windowWidth > windowHeight ? moderateScale(14) : moderateScale(12), fontFamily: 'DMSans-Bold' }}>Customer PO: {element.item.CusPo}</Text>
                                        </View>

                                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', marginVertical: windowWidth > windowHeight ? verticalScale(5) : verticalScale(5) }}>

                                            <Text style={{ color: 'black', fontSize: windowWidth > windowHeight ? moderateScale(13) : moderateScale(12), fontFamily: 'DMSans-Regular', }}>Date From: {element.item.Datefrm}</Text>
                                            <Text style={{ color: 'black', fontSize: windowWidth > windowHeight ? moderateScale(13) : moderateScale(12), fontFamily: 'DMSans-Regular', }}>Date To: {element.item.Dateto}</Text>
                                        </View>

                                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', marginVertical: windowWidth > windowHeight ? verticalScale(5) : verticalScale(5) }}>

                                            <Text style={{ color: 'black', fontSize: windowWidth > windowHeight ? moderateScale(13) : moderateScale(12), fontFamily: 'DMSans-Regular', }}>Tracking No: {element.item.TrNo}</Text>
                                            <Text style={{ color: 'black', fontSize: windowWidth > windowHeight ? moderateScale(13) : moderateScale(12), fontFamily: 'DMSans-Regular' }}>Mark For: {element.item.Markfr}</Text>
                                        </View>

                                        {isViewShown == true ?
                                            <View >

                                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', marginVertical: windowWidth > windowHeight ? verticalScale(5) : verticalScale(5) }}>

                                                    <Text style={{ color: 'black', fontSize: windowWidth > windowHeight ? moderateScale(13) : moderateScale(12), fontFamily: 'DMSans-Regular', }}>Item ID: {element.item.ItmId}</Text>
                                                    <Text style={{ color: 'black', fontSize: windowWidth > windowHeight ? moderateScale(13) : moderateScale(12), fontFamily: 'DMSans-Regular', }}>Warehouse: {element.item.Wearh}</Text>
                                                </View>

                                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', marginVertical: windowWidth > windowHeight ? verticalScale(5) : verticalScale(5) }}>

                                                    <Text style={{ color: 'black', fontSize: windowWidth > windowHeight ? moderateScale(13) : moderateScale(12), fontFamily: 'DMSans-Regular', }}>Unit Price: {element.item.UPri}</Text>
                                                    <Text style={{ color: 'black', fontSize: windowWidth > windowHeight ? moderateScale(13) : moderateScale(12), fontFamily: 'DMSans-Regular' }}>Ext Price: {element.item.EPri}</Text>
                                                </View>

                                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', marginVertical: windowWidth > windowHeight ? verticalScale(5) : verticalScale(5) }}>

                                                    <Text style={{ color: 'black', fontSize: windowWidth > windowHeight ? moderateScale(13) : moderateScale(12), fontFamily: 'DMSans-Regular', }}>Order No: {element.item.OrdNum}</Text>
                                                    <Text style={{ color: 'black', fontSize: windowWidth > windowHeight ? moderateScale(13) : moderateScale(12), fontFamily: 'DMSans-Regular' }}>Status: {element.item.Status}</Text>
                                                </View>
                                            </View>

                                            :
                                            null
                                        }


                                    </View>

                                </View>
                            </TouchableOpacity>

                        </View>

                    )

                }}
               
            />
        </View>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take one state variable which stores the id of the currently selected item and with `isViewShown==true?` you need to do this also `isViewShown==true&&selectedId==element.item.key?`

for this, in your `data` there should be a unique id.

so on `<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setFunctionality(element.item)}>`

```
const [selectedId,setSelectedId] = useState(null);
```

and in function

```
const setFunctionality = (item) => {

        setSelectedId(item.key)
        setcount(count + 1)

        if (count % 2 == 0) {
            setinitialHeight(windowWidth > windowHeight ? verticalScale(140) : verticalScale(150))
            setIsViewShown(false)

        }

        else {
            setinitialHeight(windowWidth > windowHeight ? verticalScale(170) : verticalScale(280))
            setIsViewShown(true)
        }

    }
```

For the issue you given you need to add a condition on height also based on selectedId:

```
 height:selectedId==element.item.id? initialHeight:20,
```

here instead of `20` you can take whatever initial height or normal height you want

Comment: NIce one but the 2 problems again in it.1st one is that  it shows the data of selected one but increases the height of all the views ........

Comment: 2nd one is if i select the 6th view it render the list again from1st view

Comment: see I have updated answer for first problem

Comment: do you know about 2nd problem

Comment: Not exactly....

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index to identify cards.

```
const [selectedCardIndex,setSelectedCardIndex] = useState(null);

return(<View>
<FlatList
 data={data}
 style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff', }}
 contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: '5%' }}
 renderItem={{item,index} => {
                
 return (<TouchableOpacity 
  style={{height:index==selectedCardIndex?100:50}} 
  onPress={() => selectedCardIndex(index)}>
    ...your code...
 </TouchableOpacity>)
 })
/>
```

Note: But In flatlist every card should contain the same height and width.
Instead of that you can use *scrollView*.